# Subtracting an int from a negative float adds decimal places

Tags: javascript

I want to subtract a negative `int` from a `float` in javascript:

```
10.1 - 9
```

I expected the output to be:

```
1.1
```

What I get is:

```
1.0999999999999996
```

I get this result in all browsers I have tested (latest Safari, Chrome & Firefox). I tried to convert the int to a float (`9.0`) or change the order (`-9 + 10.1`), but it remains the same.

Positive numbers work as expected. Only the negative numbers are affected.

Is there any explanation to this and is it possible to fix this behavior without rounding the result?

Comment: *"Positive numbers work as expected. Only the negative numbers are affected."* Try `0.2 + 0.1`.

Comment: Check out this thread for some good information on what you are seeing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem

Comment: @iamnotmaynard yes, it is. I have not seen this one. Shall I delete this question than?

Comment: http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?db=comics&id=2999#comic